# Excel 2015 error - no message

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a strange error on Excel, that has no error messages. Screenshot below.

[image]

I'm using the following:

- Software: Office 365 Plus
- Version: 15.0.4753.1003
- OS: Windows 7

The problem only occurs for one user. There are two users connecting via RDP. Nothing seems to appear in Event viewer, apart from the licensing service running upon startup. I have disabled all add ons on Excel.

Any ideas as to how I can identify further information on what might be causing the error or even further details about the error.

Thanks

Comment: Does the problem appear with a specific document? or all documents? if a single document, try using it on a different machine. Also, have you tried to run a repair? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: What is the user doing when these appear?

Comment: For all XLS documents. I have run full removal and re-install. Funny enough it doesn't happen when I log on. Although he also has admin rights.

Comment: I can log on as user and do noting else but simple open XLS and I receive the error.

Answer (score 0):

Not the final answer that you and I both want but I just ran into this same issue today. Although the issue does seem to be limited to Excel for some reason, it's appears to be the preview pane in Windows Explorer that instigates the error.

To verify, find any excel document on the users computer experiencing the issue and single click it to engage a preview. The error will appear every time you select an excel file. However if you hide the preview pane the error will not occur (and to confirm, disable the preview pane, single click the excel file and then enable the preview pane, the error will appear instantly).

Hopefully this information will help someone else solve the issue rather than avoiding it.